# Servlet передает null в JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Почему сервлет передает в JSP-страницу null - значение вместо текстовой строки?
Вот сервлет и метод **doGet():**

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.setAttribute("myresult", "Proba");

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/mypage.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Вот фрагмент из **mypage.jsp:**

```
<form ACTION = "/servlet/ShowParameters" method = "post" id = "formId">
<div>
    <table id = "myTable" width="100%">
           <tr>
             <td><%= request.getAttribute("myresult") %></td>
           </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

Ожидаемое значение **Proba**, а получаю **null** ?

Пробовал делать пустую **mypage.jsp** страницу. Убедился - это именно та, что выводится. Она же единственная у меня.

Comment: stack trace в студию

Comment: stack trace? Это как? Подскажите как его взять?

Comment: Кстати проверял **dispatcher** на **null** - так он не равен **null**

Comment: А вы проверяете как? Заходите непосредственно на `mypage.jsp` или через сервлет?

Comment: Вот кстати незнаю как (видимо от безысходности) зашел не на mypage.jsp а на просто mypage - и эта "сволочь" заработала! Стала отображается как надо. Я понятия не имею почему так!??

Comment: А как ещё можно из **doGet()** метода обновить **JSP**-страницу ?

Comment: А вы вообще знаете, что такое сервлет и как он привязывается к URL?

Comment: Что такое сервлет догадываюсь, а как правильно привязать к URL - покажете?

Comment: Вкратце - есть конфигурация (`web.xml` или, начиная с servlet 3.0, java-код), в которой вы задаёте, на какие адреса будет "реагировать" каждый из сервлетов (это называется servlet mapping). Если вы вводите в адресной строке один из таких адресов, обработкой запроса занимается соответствующий сервлет. Если вы вводите адрес `mypage.jsp`, то никакой сервлет не вызывается, отображается непосредственно страница `mypage.jsp` (вообще-то, можно задать сервлет и для адресов `*.jsp`, но не будем пока усложнять).

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.

поменяйте метод POST на GET в форме **mypage.jsp**

```html
<form ACTION = "/servlet/ShowParameters" method = "GET" id = "formId">
<div>
    <table id = "myTable" width="100%">
           <tr>
             <td><%= request.getAttribute("myresult") %></td>
           </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```